# Nginx Location Root Overlapped

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

In this nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name site.example.com;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        root /projects/proj1/frontend;
    }

    location /api/v1.0/ {
        root /projects/proj1;
        try_files $uri /api/v1.0/index.php$is_args$args;           

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Why every url that contains site.example.com is served by the first location, even site.example.com/api/v1.0/ ? Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've already tried to invert the order, so first /api/v1.0/ and second /, but with no luck.

EDIT2: Trying with curl the response is correct, but chrome keep using caching even in incognito...

Comment: It is due to the order of the location blocks.  Please [read](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms), specifically the section entitled "How Nginx Chooses Which Location to Use to Handle Requests"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've already tried to invert the order. It works only the first time: I visit /api/v1.0/ -> OK, then / -> OK, then /api/v1.0/ NOPE.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior in nginx. `location /` basically matches everything. If you want to match `/` only, use exact location: `location = /`